# Python : How To Build a Report in Python with Multiple Pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pdf

I'm hoping to build a report/dashboard entirely in python and have it export to PDF. I have two pandas dataframes built and I would need to add two text boxes(Tournament Name/Date & Weekly Winner). Is it possible to combine everything into one nicely formatted pdf in python?

I'm looking for a very high level answer, is it possible and if so how would i go about doing it.

Right now i export the df to excel and then copy it over to another excel file and format the tables and files. I'd really like to automate this entire process.

This is the report that's created in excel and saved as a pdf:

[image]

Comment: Copy-paste is usually faster, but you can create a script that will rewrite the whole Excel file.

Comment: You could try using pandas styling: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Builtin-styles

Comment: @kate-melnykova Can you give me some more info about what you mean create a script? A script in python or in excel or something else? I'm just looking to automate this in any way that I can, so if there's a way to automate this in excel I'm all for it, I just don't know how.